# I broke npm on cloud 9 Amazon aws

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, npm, aws-cloud9

I ran

```
npm config set prefix /usr/local
```

because i tried to fix something else without thinking before.

Now i can't install any packages anymore.

```
pm ERR! Error: UNABLE_TO_GET_ISSUER_CERT_LOCALLY
```

Is there a way to reset all settings on cloud 9?

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution:

```
npm config delete prefix
```